# BeforeNavigate2 & Refresh

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, twebbrowser, delphi-xe4

Why doesn't OnRefresh or OnPreRefresh fire BeforeNavigate2 when using this code. According to 
 [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325079) it is a bug but how to workaround it in Delphi? I am using EmbeddedWB with IE10.

```
EmbeddedWB1.Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
EmbeddedWB1.Refresh; // doesn't fire BeforeNavigate2
```

Comment: You should mention that the `Webbrowser1` is declared as `TEmbeddedWB` type. Please edit your question and include this information.

Comment: @TLama Ah i forgot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather simple solution to a stupid problem.

```
const
  DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE = $00004000;

procedure Refresh(const Sender: TCustomEmbeddedWB);
var
  Flag: OleVariant;
begin
  Flag:=DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE;
  Sender.Navigate(Sender.LocationURL,Flag);
end;

procedure EmbeddedWB1Refresh(Sender: TCustomEmbeddedWB; CmdID: Integer;
  var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  Cancel:=True;
  Refresh(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: Really a solution ? That's what the [`IWebBrowser2::Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768258(v=vs.85).aspx) should currently do. See the remarks section of that reference page...

Comment: @TLama EmbeddedWB.Refresh/Refresh2 will not fire DocumentComplete nor OnBeforeNavigate2. This will.

Comment: Well, except the `DocumentComplete` and `BeforeNavigate2` events, the `Refresh` and `Refresh2` methods doesn't even change the `Busy` flag nor `ReadyState` value. So your code might really be the right workaround for your problem. [+1]

Comment: @TLama Can we chat :) I have a question regarding TEmbeddedWB.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigate2` is an asynchronous operation. By following it with `Refresh`, you're not giving the navigation a chance to start and fire `BeforeNavigate2` event. Perhaps, you should wait for `NavigateComplete2` to get fired, before calling `Refresh`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? The bug you refer to is not related to your Delphi code, it was specific to .NET and got fixed long ago.

**[EDITED]**. What I said above was incorrect. It might have been true for IE7, but for IE10, both `BeforeNavigate2` and `NavigateComplete2` do get fired (once), even if `Navigate` call is immediately followed with `Refresh`. However, that doesn't trigger `OLECMDID_PREREFRESH` or `OLECMDID_REFRESH` commands to be sent by WebBrowser control to its site COM object. I only saw `OLECMDID_PREREFRESH` coming through when I manually triggered a refresh via right-click menu (but still **no** `OLECMDID_REFRESH`). This has been verified with C++/ATL/VS2012. Unfortunately, this doesn't help to answer why the behavior is different with Delphi.

Comment: Refresh doesn't fire BeforeNavigate2 at all. It doesn't matter when you call it.

Comment: @user2665920, I dealt with a similar issue back in IE7 days. I'm going to verify it with a modern version and get back here.

Comment: This is not related to Delphi, but to the `IWebBrowser2` interface itself. Those events are not being fired by the interface if you call the `Refresh` method on it. There's more than this; even `Busy` flag is not set and even the `ReadyState` value doesn't change.

Comment: True. I might have misunderstood @user2665920 's question: got it as though there is no `BeforeNavigate2` event in Delphi, despite there's a call to `EmbeddedWB1.Navigate`, followed by `EmbeddedWB1.Refresh`.